# what is difference between $\int_{0}^{1+x^3}\sqrt{t}$ and $\int_{0}^{x^3}\sqrt{1+t}$ and $\int_{0}^{x}\sqrt{1+t^3}$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> Given $f(x)=\sqrt{1+x^3}$, which of the following is the correct integral?
>
> - $\int_{0}^{1+x^3}\sqrt{t}dt$
> - $\int_{0}^{x^3}\sqrt{1+t}dt$
> - $\int_{0}^{x}\sqrt{1+t^3}dt$

How are they all not the same thing? Don't you just replace the $t$ inside of the integrals with the top values on the integral sign?

Comment: Absolutely not. You might be thinking of the FTOC, which says $\int_a^b f(x)\,dx=F(b)-F(a)$, where $F$ is an antiderivative of $f$. So the bounds of the integral are substituted in $F$, not into the integrand $f$.

Comment: What variable are you integrating against? $dx$ or $dt$. And what are your limits for $\int{\sqrt{1+x^3}$. Key details are missing...

Comment: @RhysHughes whoops thanks for the catch lemme fix it real quick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us define
$$
f_1(x)=\int_0^{1+x^3}\sqrt t~dt,
$$
$$
f_2(x)=\int_0^{x^3}\sqrt{1+t}~dt
$$
and
$$
f_3(x)=\int_0^x\sqrt{1+t^3}~dt.
$$
With the substitution $s=1+t$ you get
$$
f_2(x)=\int_1^{1+x^3}\sqrt s ~ds = \int_0^{1+x^3}\sqrt s~ds-\int_0^1\sqrt s~ds = f_1(x)-\frac23.
$$
You see that $f_1$ and $f_2$ are not the same function.

I don't know if there exists a nice closed form of $f_3$, but we can easily see that it has to be different from $f_1$ and $f_2$. Using FTOC we get
$$
f_3'(x)=\sqrt{1+x^3}.
$$
If you compute $f_1(x)=\left[\frac23t^{3/2}\right]_0^{1+x^3}=\frac23(1+x^3)^{3/2}$, then using the chain rule implies
$$
f_1'(x)=\sqrt{1+x^3}\cdot3x^2\neq\sqrt{1+x^3}=f_3'(x).
$$
Because the derivative is unique, the functions $f_1$ and $f_3$ can't be the same. And further $f_1'=f_2'$, so $f_1$, $f_2$ and $f_3$ are all different functions!

Answer (score 1):

We have that given $f(x)$ the integral over $[a,b]$ is given by

$$\int_a^b f(t) \,dt$$

then the correct solution for $f(x)=\sqrt{1+x^3}$ is $$\int_{0}^{3}\sqrt{1+t^3}\,dt$$

Comment: @Sebastiano Thanks! Really appreciated, Bye!

Answer (score 1):

Note that 
$$\int_0^{x} f(t) dt = \int_{0}^{x} \sqrt{1+t^3}\, dt.$$
If you want to use $\sqrt{1+t}$ instead of using $\sqrt{1+t^3}$, you need to do the substitution properly. For example, if we substitute $y=t^3$ then $dt = \frac{1}{3 y^{2/3}} dy$. So
$$\int_0^{x} f(t) dt = \int_{0}^{x} \sqrt{1+t^3}\, dt = \int_0^{x^3} \frac{\sqrt{1+y}}{3y^{2/3}} dy= \int_0^{x^3} \frac{\sqrt{1+t}}{3t^{2/3}} dt \neq \int_{0}^{x^3} \sqrt{1+t} dt.$$

---

Perhaps, a simpler example would clarify how substitution works. Suppose $h(x) = x^2$ and you want to compute $\int_{0}^{2} h(x) dx$. It is easy to see that
$$I = \int_{0}^{2} x^2 dx = \frac{8}{3}.$$
Now if we do what you wrote then
$$I = \int_{0}^{2^2} x dx = 4 \neq \frac{8}{3}.$$
Which means that we are missing something in the integrand. Indeed, by setting $t = x^2 \implies dx = \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{t}} dt$, we get
$$I = \int_{0}^{2} x^2 dx = \int_{0}^{4} t \cdot \frac{1}{2 \sqrt{t}} dt = \frac{8}{3}.$$
Hopefully, this would clarify the mistake you are doing.